# Inide 3D Game Development with limited hardware

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, tao-framework

I have a great deal of experience in VB, C#/Java and slightly less in C from school and my own interest/family involvement. I have created many 2D side-scrolling games, both with libraries and entirely from scratch.
I don't have a great deal of money and so I haven't upgraded/purhased a new computer (desktop or a replacement laptop) since I got my current one some 5years ago. It runs fairly slowly (around 1.4ghz, has 2gb RAM and no deadicated grahpics. I run Windows (Vista))

My idea for a game is a static structure, such as a tower block or a crane for example on which the player (through first person view) would walk around and interact with objects to complete the game - much like a Portal style game, just without the portals or any in-hand objects.

I'd prefer to use C# with the TAO Framework wrapper on the OpenGL Library, but I know this is not everyones first choice.

So:
Is this method of C# + TAO a good one, or should I scrap this and work with OpenGL and C/C++ or another language+wrapper/toolkit that might be easier to use?

Is a first-person view more or less difficult than third-person view to impliment for games? (I assumed first is easier as you don't have to use a player model and animations and the code behind them)

On my limited hardware, is a grahpics/CPU intensive game like with OpenGL going to be worthwile or will it be more of a challenge with my current (lacking) computer? If not - are their any other 3D alternatives to use - such as the Blender Game Engine which runs (just) on my computer?

Would I be better using some prewritten Engine and/or Grahpic extenion libraries, or since this is more of an learning adventure, would writting a lot of the 'engine' like code myself be a good idea?

Comment: These questions are almost all subjective, and thus not a good fit for this site. It's not 'better' to use one language over another, and it's not 'better' to write your own engine or to use a premade one. It just all boils down to what your personal goals are. Best of luck.

Comment: Consider that the Nintendo 64, well-known for its 3D games, had a 93 Mhz CPU. If that kind of hardware can support _Ocarina of Time_, think of what you can do, with hardware 15 times faster :-). Incidentally, OOT's engine was originally forked from Mario 64's, so the lesson there is, "if you want to make the best game in the world, use an already existing engine"

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL has been around for a long while, it should work as expected.

Just create your game with your current hardware, use those limitations to learn how to optimize your code and graphics to make it run as smoothly as possible.

Check the OpenTK (which replaced TAO) library and run the demo/samples; those should give you a good indication what your hardware can do with those.

Remember that there are great games running on cell phones these days; those have really limited resources.

Good luck.

Comment: You mention OpenTK. I am still working on the basics of OpenGL through the Superbible book. The book uses calls from the glut library. I have found that only TAO has the exact glut functions, which OpenTK does not, or if it does they are merged with other functions.